# Why doesn't this IOException throw inside an async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this block of code in an async method:

```
private async Task DownloadAsync(string url, string filepath)
{
    var response = await Client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

It is being called like this:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(DownloadAsync("https://...", "c:\path\on\disk"));
...    
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

If the file is in use, FileStream should throw an IOException. And if I put this block into a try-catch, it indeed catches it.

However if I leave it unhandled, the application doesn't crash or raise the exception.. it just does nothing.

Do I have to manually check for exceptions on async tasks somehow? Or is there something else that I do not understand?

edit: added how it's being called and more contextual info

Comment: How are you calling the method that this code is in?

Comment: How is the async method defined?

Comment: @DavidG I updated the question with more context

Comment: @Nkosi updated with more context

Comment: Exceptions are propagated when you `await`. If you never `await`, then there is nobody to raise the exception to. (Where would you catch the exception that nobody ever awaits?) [Further discussion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2014/12/10/async-exceptions-in-c/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an `async` method encounters an unhandled exception, the exception is temporarily stored, then thrown when the method's task is awaited. This simple example demonstrates:

```
public static async Task Foo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Simulating async with a tiny delay");
    await Task.Delay(1);

    Console.WriteLine("Throwing");
    throw new Exception("Foo");
}   

public static async Task MainAsync()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    Console.WriteLine("Adding task");
    tasks.Add(Foo());

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting one second");
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    Console.WriteLine("Awaiting task");
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}


public static void Main()
{
    MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Output:

```
Adding task
Simulating async with a tiny delay
Waiting one second
Throwing
Awaiting task
Run-time exception (line 15): Foo
```

As you can see, the console logs "Throwing" but no exception gets thrown. Instead, it gets thrown later, after the console logs "Awaiting task".

[Demo on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/utXoYS)